# Sharepoint 2007 display aspx code

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm facing problem with SharePoint 2007. I installed a solution using Sharepoint installer for new web application, after installing I go to browser to navigate the .aspx page the browser show all source code of aspx page. 
I tried to re-install by run the command aspnet_regiis -i but it did not success.

Please help me this issue.